# Integrating ECSLidingViewController for my UITaBBarController app

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

Am stuck up in implementing facebook slide menu kind of view using `ECSlidingViewController` source code [**https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController**] for my requirement.

My need is: I have a loginScreen and then next is a `UITabBarController` with 5 tabs. When I click on the 2nd tab, I need this 2nd tab VC to act as a central VC with a `UIBarButtonItem` on the RIGHT side of Nav Bar. When I click on the `UIBarButtonItem` I need facebook kind of sliding view to appear. Please let me know how do I integrate this. This should be done in Storyboards.

Comment: Yes I hve started with storyboard. Login screen is done and on clikng LOGIN m able to enter TabBarControllers page. And on click on each tab I have diffrent ViewControllers set up. Now,on click of a bar button item on the right (in any tab), I want to integrate this ECSlidingViewController code and want that side menu to appear/disappear. help me out..

Answer (score 1):

Your second tab can be a reference to `ECSlidingViewController`. Your view controller relationships would look something like this:

```
UITabBarController's second tab -> ECSlidingViewController
ECSlidingViewController's topViewController -> UINavigationController
ECSlidingViewController's underRightViewController -> a view controller your users will see when the top view is anchored to the left
UINavigationController's rootViewController -> some view controller your users will see as the second tab
```

You can setup a right bar button item on the navigation controller to anchor the top view to the left.